# Excel OBDC - SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, vba

I am trying to use Excel pull data from a large Oracle Data Warehouse via an ODBC connection. I have a query that works using the editor in Access. I've tried using Power Query and Microsoft SQL to use this query to get this data into Excel and I get errors.

Therefore:

1. Does SQL executed from Excel need to be in a different syntax? Shouldn't it still be Oracle?
2. How can I use this pre-written query to ping the data warehouse and get what I need?

Here is the SQL that I have so far. I had to change some table names...sorry if that makes it weird.

Comment: I think you are looking for the setting "pass through query". Not sure where it is located in your set up.

Comment: The pass-through query option (in Access) was not selected. Does the original query need to be written as a PTQ, then copied to Excel?

The goal is to avoid Access entirely and JUST use Excel to query what we need from the data warehouse.

I know that VBA code can be used to execute an SQL query but I'm pretty poor at VBA so I'd like to avoid that (at least for now)

Comment: That depends on what driver you are using. Share your queries - I think that'll help others help  you

Comment: Just did. Than you for your suggestion

Comment: SQL doesnt have a VAL function. That's only Access.

Comment: Would it be advisable to just rewrite this as an SQL query and then try and use it through Excel?

Comment: Add a data connection in your Excel workbook using your ODBC data source.  You can then write (or paste) your SQL into the data connection.  Many of my queries need "set nocount on" to work properly in Excel.

Comment: @Degan I just tried adding that and still no luck. I think braX was onto something -- the syntax for this Access SQL and actual SQL are different. Will that make a difference?

Comment: I would not use SQL generated by Access (or Excel).  I suggest writing your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL you posted uses Access-specific functions. That is NOT a valid SQL query if run directly against Oracle. If you have a bunch of linked tables in Access, that would allow this.

The ODBC datasource connection in Excel works differently. ODBC executes the query  directly at the datasource. It does some validation first and supports a limited subset of SQL language supported at the destination. What's included in the subset is determined in part by the driver selected for the connection.

So what you want to do is use a tool that lets you build the query directly in an Oracle environment, like Quest Toad or Oracle SQL Developer. Once you have the query working there, it should be easier to port it to Excel.

One thing I like to do is put my query into a view on the database. Then I can just select everything from the view when creating the Excel connection.

It's also worth pointing you to the My Data Sources folder. When you first setup an ODBC connection in Excel, the connection is saved by default in Windows in a folder called "My Data Sources" located just under your user profile folder. For example: `C:\Users\UserName\My Data Sources\Data Source Name.odc`.

You can open these `*.odc` files in any text editor, and you should be able to manually edit the SQL here. Especially look for the `<odc:CommandText>` element. In this way you can build a simple query up front, and then improve on the SQL command in your favorite environment and easily move the updated SQL to the existing ODBC connection.

Comment: Thanks Joel Coehoorn for your answer. It definitely solved the problem.